# C#.NET: Retrieve list of computers in a FOLDER in a domain

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, active-directory, directoryservices

How do I Retrieve a list of computers in a FOLDER in a domain.
lets say i have maydomain.dom as my domain
and I have a folder containing some computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code to list out computers in your domain and in active directory, this may help you

```
//ActiveDirectorySearch1
//Displays all computer names in an Active Directory
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices; 
namespace ActiveDirectorySearch1
{
class Class1
{
static void Main (string[] args)
{
//Note : microsoft is the name of my domain for testing purposes.
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP://microsoft);
DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
mySearcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=computer)");
Console.WriteLine("Listing of computers in the Active Directory"); 
Console.WriteLine("============================================"); foreach(SearchResult resEnt in mySearcher.FindAll())
{ 
Console.WriteLine(resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry().Name.ToString()); }
Console.WriteLine("=========== End of Listing ============="); 
}
}
}
```

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jodonnell/ListAllComps07022005005654AM/ListAllComps.aspx

Comment: Thanks but I need to know how get the computers in a SPECIFIC FOLDER in my domain

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the same but maybe you can use the same principle as in this blog post: [Find users in Active Directory folder using GUID](http://khlavkalashcode.blogspot.com/2009/04/find-users-in-active-directory-folder.html)